# What's the origin of the Hong Kong colloquialism "I go to school by bus"?

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, internet-slang

I've seen this phrase being used frequently on social media amongst the youth of Hong Kong.

> I go to school by bus

Would anyone kindly explain how this phrase came to be and what it means?

From my understanding it's the result of deliberately transliterating the original Chinese phrase in a mocking manner, but I could be wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: web search:Cinema  
[Full-Eng.sub] Hong Kong BL movie - 放肆 - I Go To School Not By Bus.mp4

I Go To School Not By Bus (2011) A coming out of age story of 2 secondary school students who study in a Christian school. Ming, is in closet and Hei is openly gay, "I go to school not by bus" is a story of self-discovery, struggle thru love, loneliness, religion in the no-regret-rebellious-moment.

Comment: 「I go to school by bus」可謂小學必學語句，不過上到中學、甚至考DSE文憑試時再用，唔會唔因為語句太簡單而被扣分？有網友在Facebook群組名校Secrets發帖，有老師指六個字的語句太簡單，如果DSE用到，只能拿2級成績。但若然變成意思相同的「The method of transportation I choose to go to school is by public vehicle」，馬上能摘5，惹來網友熱列討論。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a troll response commonly used in the Hong Kong Online Forum "HKGolden". The line was originally from a Primary School Textbook's dialogue and was usually being used as a ridiculous and nonsense reply to English-related questions on the forum.

Check [here](http://evchk.wikia.com/wiki/I_go_to_school_by_bus) for the Hong Kong Local Encyclopedia page on this phrase.